# Shortcut key for 'View in Object Browser'

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know if there is a shortcut key for viewing the selected object (in the text editor) in the object browser?

I am sure there was one, but I cannot find it, or anything that seems to work in the key bindings dialog.

eg:

string test = string.empty;

```
if (string.isnullorempty(test))
{                          ^ caret here
    ...
}
```

pressing the key would open the object browser to System.String

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but here's another way to open the Object Browser with some context.  In Solution Explorer, if you expand References and right-click a reference, there is an option to 'View in Object Browser'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>F12</kbd> will go to the source (if you have it), or the object browser if it's in a referenced assembly.

Comment: It navigates to a source code definition (from metadata) for me, even for referenced assemblies.

Comment: Was working for me before, now not, only Ctrl-Alt-J working now, how to get back F12? I did install 'MVC 3 Tools Updates' but don't think that it could be the case.

Comment: Is there any way to open **any** reference in object browser instead of generated metadata code - like in VB? Perhaps I should write an extension for this.

Comment: Is there a way to force opening a symbol in OB in C# projects??

Answer (score 17):

This navigates to the correct class inside the object browser.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, then right click in the results and select Browse Definition

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, then type the name in the search box

Comment: Unfortunately, `Shift + Alt + F12` (Edit.QuickFindSymbol) is pretty hit-or-miss.

Answer (score 7):

Use Ctrl-Alt-J.

Comment: Doesn't navigate the the object though :(

Comment: CTRL+ALT+J only opens the object browser, and doesn't navigate to the object you're currently selecting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is CTRL + ALT + J

Here is the reference: [Object Browser Shortcut Keys, Visual C++ 6.0 Default Shortcut Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ztdfwss8.aspx)

Comment: The link provided is no longer useful.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found doing it with a single shortcut is through ReSharper and define.

Editor context menu. codewindow.navigate.resharper_navigatetoobjectbrowser 
as alt +shift +  j (or what you want). Maybe there is a way to create a code, link it to the functions and add the shortcut in this window without installing ReSharper, or open a ticket to visual studio teem

[the shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3DLT.png)

Answer (score 1):

It used to be Ctrl + LeftMouseClick on what you want to search for (around 2015), but it does not work anymore in VS 2019.

Answer (score -2):

Resharper navigates to the class in object browser when you press F12