# Visual Studio for Mac 2022 "Go to Definition" in "using" lines doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-mac

I created a simple console project with the following:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonExample
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Create an instance of a class to serialize
            Person person = new Person
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Doe",
                Age = 30
            };

            // Serialize the object to a JSON string
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);

            // Print the JSON string
            Console.WriteLine(json);

            // Deserialize the JSON string back into an object
            Person deserializedPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);

            // Print the values of the deserialized object
            Console.WriteLine($"{deserializedPerson.FirstName} {deserializedPerson.LastName}, Age {deserializedPerson.Age}");
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then I placed the cursor/caret above the Json part of `using Newtonsoft.Json;`, did the "Go to Definition" functionality in Visual Studio so I could see more about this namespace but it returned a window saying: 'Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret.'. On every other package installed via NuGet this happens and I don't know why. I obviously added the package to the project and it also builds without any issues.

I was expecting something like JetBrains Rider:

[image]

Comment: A workaround would be to right click on JsonConvert and select 'Go to Definition' this will open that type in the Assembly Viewer, and then you can browse the rest of the Newtonsoft.Json assembly. The Assembly Viewer will show a similar view to what is in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Those commands are only for direct symbol access. The only way I know of is Object Browser,then search or navigate to what you want to look at.

This is the same behavior as Visual Studio on Windows as well.

There is a similar question that might be a little helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20216717/3885008

> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, then right click in
> the results and select Browse Definition

But, that is about as close as I could find to what you want to do with a `using` statement for a namespace.

Answer (score -1):

I've approached Microsoft with the same question I asked here in Stack Overflow and the reality is that the feature I was looking for is not available as of 2022 in any Visual Studio Edition. If you want to check more information on this please check my thread at Microsoft Developers Community https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Going-to-definitions-on-locally-installe/10236228. As an alternative you can use JetBrains Rider which has this feature allowing to navigate through dependencies decompiled assemblies.